# Angular Date time conversion

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to convert the time and date from an html5 input to our countries format.

I'm trying to convert this: 2018-05-23 03:00
To this: 23-05-2018 03:00

I'm using angulars DatePipe like this:

```
var newDateBegin = this.dateFilter.transform(this.newDateBeginString.replace("T", " "), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM");
```

I have to replace the T in the string because for some reason the HTML5 input outputs it like this: 2018-05-23T03:00

But after converting it using: 2018-05-23 03:00, i get the following result:
2018-05-23 03:05.
No matter what time I put in there it always ends with xx:05. Am I missing something?

this is how i create the DatePipe:

```
private dateFilter: DatePipe = new DatePipe("nl-NL");
```

Comment: As @Christian just mentioned, you are getting the month due to the uppercase 'MM', change it to mm to get minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't HH:MM the problem? M (uppercase) gets the month. Try to change it.

> Month - MM - Numeric: 2 digits + zero padded

Use mm, as explained [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

> "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"